# UglifyJS gives an error: Unexpected character '`' (line: 315, col: 14)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to minify my JS, and while running uglifyjs, I get the above error. The code in question looks like this:

```
    template: `
<div style="padding: 7px;">
    <h1>Betalinger</h1>

    <div v-if="is_error || is_info" v-bind:class="{ 'alert-danger': is_error, 'alert-info': is_info }" class="alert">{{ msg }}</div>

    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p v-if="app.subscription.id && subscriptionStatus == 'active'">{{ app.subscription.stripe_plan | translatePlan }}</p>
        <p v-else-if="subscriptionStatus == 'none'">Intet Aktivt Abonnement</p>

        <p v-if="subscriptionStatus == 'canceled'">Abonnement er blevet annuleret og er aktivt indtil {{ app.subscription.ends_at | endsAt }}</p>
    </div>
...
`
```

where the `...` are omitted code. The point is, it's that single quote, i dont remember the name, that is the problem. What can i do?

Comment: Do you use a `\`` anywhere inside the template literal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`uglify-js` can only minify ES5 source code. The tagged template literals are an ES6 feature. In order for `uglify-js` to minify your code, you first have to transpile it down to ES5. The other alternative is to use [uglify-es](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) which supports ES6.

Comment: Correct link to uglify-es / uglify-js2: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2 or https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/harmony (without `)